# How do I use Context in the nested static class below without memory leak or Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference exception?

Tags: java, android, static-methods

I want to use Context in the static class below in the do in background method. I have tried parsing context in the constructor and also creating an instance of the class but every time I get this error :
 `Attempt to invoke virtual method java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir() on a null object reference`

```java
     public static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, 
      Void> {
        private PicDao picDao;
        Context context;

        public PopulateDbAsyncTask(PictureDataBase db, Contex context) {
            picDao = db.picDao();
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            return null;
         }
}
```

Comment: Your `context` is null until you initialize it. You'll have to pass your current Context into a constructor.

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath that's what I said in my question. I have tried that but still the same null error.

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you pass not null context value into the constructor. Use Application context for this purpose.